# Uniform convergence of $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)^n$ in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> How to show uniform convergence of $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-x)^n$$ for $x$ in $(0,1)$ ?

I know I have to find the convergence radius but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Note that
$$
0\leq\sum_{n=0}^m x^n(1-x)^n\le \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{4^n}
$$
and use the fact that $\sum_0^\infty 4^{-n}$ converges. Now let $m\to \infty$.

Comment: That's not a proof: It's quite possible to find continuous nonnegative $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ such that for all $m$ and all $x\in [0,1],$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}f_n(x)\le \sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{4^n},$$

yet $\sum_{n=0}^{m}f_n(x)$ fails to converge uniformly.

Comment: @zhw.  You might consider showing an example of such a function.  Hope you're doing well.

Answer (score 0):

Radius of convergence is given by $|x(1-x)|=1$ or $x^2-x-1=0$.  Solution is $x=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Use smaller magnitude value to get $r=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us use calculus to find the maximun of $f$ in $[0,1]$ :

Here
$f(x)=x^n(1-x)^n$. Then  $$f'(x)=n(x-x^2)^{n-1}(1-2x)$$

Now $f'(x)=0$ if $x-x^2=0$ or $1-2x=0$, which is happen if $x=0$ or $1$ or $1/2$

That is, $0,1,1/2$ are critical points

Here $f(0)=0=f(1)$ and $f(1/2)=\frac{1}{4^n}$

Hence the maximum of $f $ is $\frac{1}{4^n}$.

That is, $$f(x) \leq \frac{1}{4^n}$$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

Now use Foobaz John hint  to conclude your result!